# Critique & improve a file reading routine

Tags: common-lisp

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(defun read-sim-file (filename)
  "Reads file.
File is presumed to be the output from a simulation.

Returns lines from the simulation as a list of strings

We throw an error if TRAP ET is detected.

Lines with DBG_INT are ignored."
  (let ((file-text-list (split "\\n"
                   (batteries:read-text-file filename)))
    (return_list '()))

    (loop for line in file-text-list do
     (cond ((scan "DBG_INT" line)
        )  ; intentional newline.
           ((scan "TRAP ET" line)
        (error "Trap ET detected"))
           (t
        ;; There's got to be a cleaner method here.
        (setf return_list (append return_list (list line))))))
    return_list))
```

This code is ugly.
In particular, the (setf X (append X Y)) idiom feels hideously clunky.

Comments on how to make this more beautiful?

Possibly REMOVE-IF?

Answer (score 3):

At first glance, you're looking for `loop`s `collect` clause.

```
(defun read-sim-file (filename)
  (let ((file-text-list (split "\\n" (batteries:read-text-file filename))))
    (loop for line in file-text-list 
      when (scan "TRAP ET" line)
        do (error "Trap ET detected o_o")
      unless (scan "DBG_INT" line)
        collect line)))
```

At second glance, you can do this much more efficiently using `with-open-file` instead of breaking your input file up into a list (this should save you two traversals of said file)

```
(defun read-sim-file (filename)
  (with-open-file (stream filename)
    (loop for line = (read-line stream nil 'eof) until (eq line 'eof)
      when (scan "TRAP ET" line)
        do (error "Trap ET detected ಠ_ಠ")
      unless (scan "DBG_INT" line)
        collect line)))
```

The first one is a fairly basic [loop directive](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html), the second one is almost verbatum an example out of [the CL Cookbook "files" section](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/files.html) (the whole cookbook contains many other useful recipes too).

Just as a sidenote, do try to [indent things properly](http://dept-info.labri.fr/~idurand/enseignement/lst-info/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html). It was more difficult than it should have been to read your initial program. If you ever catch yourself leaving comments like `;; intentional newline`, think hard about what you just wrote.

---

Now that I've had some proper sleep, lets take the new one apart for educational purposes.

```
  (with-open-file (stream filename)
```

This line opens up a file and creates a handle for it named `stream`. Nothing has actually been read yet, you've just got a stream to pull from.

```
    (loop for line = (read-line stream nil 'eof) until (eq line 'eof)
```

`loop` has a couple of non-obvious directives. This is one of them (and coincidentally, the reason that some lispers prefer the non-standard [`iterate`](http://common-lisp.net/project/iterate/) module; there's a feeling that infix notation isn't Lispy enough. I disagree, just like to point it out).

`read-line` takes a stream and a few options and returns the first line from that stream. `(read-line stream nil 'eof)` means "Read the next line from `stream`, don't error at the end of file marker (that's the `nil`) and return the symbol `eof` when you reach the end of the file.

The full line then reads "Loop through the lines in `stream` until you hit `'eof`".

```
      when (scan "TRAP ET" line)
        do (error "Trap ET detected ಠ_ಠ")
```

`loop` has conditional directives too, so you don't need to resort to `cond` here. `if`, `else`, `when` and `unless` are all valid forms.

```
      unless (scan "DBG_INT" line)
```

Speaking of `unless`, you can use it to skip "DBG_INT" lines without devoting a separate clause to them.

```
        collect line))
```

This does the same thing as

```
     (setf tmp (append return_list (list line)))
```

which is to say, it creates a list where the elements are collected in order they're encountered (though there isn't an actual named variable that). The `loop` form also returns whatever you've collected if that's the last clause in the statement (so you don't need to explicitly return it).